# REST service semantics; include properties not being updated?

Tags: json, rest, service, asp.net-web-api

Suppose I have a resource called `Person`.  I can update `Person` entities by doing a `POST` to `/data/Person/{ID}`.  Suppose for simplicity that a person has three properties, first name, last name, and age.

`GET /data/Person/1` yields something like:

`{ id: 1, firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith", age: 30 }`.

My question is about updates to this person and the semantics of the services that do this.  Suppose I wanted to update John, he's now 31.  In terms of design approach, I've seen APIs work two ways:

**Option 1:**

`POST /data/Person/1` with `{ id: 1, age: 31 }` does the right thing.  Implicitly, any property that isn't mentioned isn't updated.

**Option 2:**

`POST /data/Person/1` with the full object that would have been received by `GET` -- all properties must be specified, even if many don't change, because the API (in the presence of a missing property) would assume that its proper value is `null`.

Which option is correct from a recommended design perspective?   Option 1 is attractive because it's short and simple, but has the downside of being ambiguous in some cases.  Option 2 has you sending a lot of data back and forth even if it's not changing, and doesn't tell the server what's really important about this payload (only the age changed).

Comment: Personally, in projects where I've implmented RESTful APIs, I've always done option 1, but that's just my opinion on the matter. This question is really up to you as the developer. As an aside, if you are developing a RESTful api, you should be using a `PUT` instead of a `POST` to update a record

Comment: So @mituw16 when using option 1, if you need to update a property to be null you send it explicitly?

Comment: yes when attempting to null out a property, I pass back null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option 1 - updating a subset of the resource - is now formalised in HTTP as the PATCH method. Option 2 - updating the whole resource - is the PUT method.

In real-world scenarios, it's common to want to upload only a subset of the resource. This is better for performance of the request and modularity/diversity of clients.

For that reason, PATCH is now more useful than PUT in a typical API (imo), though you can support both if you want to. There are a few corner cases where a platform may not support PATCH, but I believe they are rare now.

If you do support both, don't just make them interchangeable. The difference with PUT is, if it receives a subset, it should assume the whole thing was uploaded, so should then apply default properties to those that were omitted, or return an error if they are required. Whereas PATCH would just ignore those omitted properties.